# m.add is not a function (new node js module)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node js and create module as follow.
What I got is m.add is not a function at Object.anonymous

Module.js

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
    exports.add = add;
    exports.multiply = multiply;

    function add(number1, number2) {
        return parseInt(number1, 10) + parseInt(number2, 10);
    }

    function multiply(number1, number2) {
        return parseInt(number1, 10) * parseInt(number2, 10);
    }
});
```

App.js

```
var m = require('./module');

console.log(m.add(3, 5));
console.log(m.multiply(4, 5));
```

Comment: You're creating anonymous function but you never call it.

Comment: What is not working in your code is the order you wrote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you're wrapping your code like that, but here's how `module.js` should look:

```
function add(number1, number2) {
  return parseInt(number1, 10) + parseInt(number2, 10);
}

function multiply(number1, number2) {
  return parseInt(number1, 10) * parseInt(number2, 10);
}

// don't export your functions individually
// export them on an object (which is how you use them in your app)
module.exports = {
  add: add,
  multiply: multiply
}
```

If you want you can *also* do individual exports for your functions (like you have in *your* `module.js`), but it doesn't look like you need too.

Comment: I think the IIFE signature used in the question above is used by node.js internally to wrap module logic.